# Deleting a node from a doubly linked list

Tags: c, doubly-linked-list

This is my current code which i have messed with so how im dealing with the first item or only item are wrong, which are the first 2 parts to this function. For some reason i am getting memory errors if i just try to set node=node->next_.. i would assume this would be the easiest way but when i throw that back into the program i start getting memory access issues. all other parts work fine as long as i don't manipulate the head address.

```
void removeNode(struct student_record_node* node)
{
    struct student_record_node *temp=NULL;
    temp=node;
    if(node->next_==NULL&&node->prev_==NULL)
    {
        node=node->next_
        free(node->prev_);
    }
    else if(node->prev_==NULL&& node->next_!=NULL)
    {
        node=node->next_
        free(node->prev_);
    }

    else if(node->next_!=NULL && node->prev_!=NULL)
    {
        node->prev_->next_ = node->next_;
        node->next_->prev_ = node->prev_;
        student_record_node_deallocate(node);
    }
    else if(node->prev_!=NULL&& node->next_==NULL)
    {
        node->prev_->next_=node->next_;
        student_record_node_deallocate(node);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post a [Minimal Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). The root cause may or may not be in this code or in this code alone.

Comment: In a doubly linked list there should never ever be a null node pointer to next or prev. If there is only 1 node it points to itself. `node->next->prev = node->prev; node->prev->next = node->next; free(node);`

Comment: @WalterM It is not necessary that doubly linked list should not contain any null pointer.  In a doubly linked list prev of head node is NULL and next of last node is NULL. What you are saying is present in the circular link list.

Comment: If you want to change the node of the head pointer, I think you need to pass address of the `headptr` and catch it with a double pointer

Answer (score 1):

There are several errors：

1. The node may be the head,  so `struct student_record_node*` should be returned, instead of `void`.
2. node may be `NULL`
3. if `node->prev_` is `NULL`, make sure to free the node deleted.

Comment: `free` with a `NULL` parameter will not cause major problems. From the [free man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/free): "If ptr is NULL, no operation is performed."

Answer (score 1):

Since you did not provide, what your linked list looks like, I am going to assume for my code-example, that it is a struct containing a pointer to the `head` of the linked list (the first element). It is referred to by `your_list`.

The problem lies within the first two `if`-blocks in your code;

- The first `if`: `if(!node->next_ && !node->prev_)`:

  This means you are deleting the head-element of the list. In this case, you will have to explicitly set the head to `NULL`, instead of setting the pointer to the node you wish to delete to `NULL` (by setting it to its predecessor, which is `NULL`). Also, you are freeing a `NULL`-Pointer, by freeing the previous node. This is in it self not a problem, but you want to delete `node`, not it's predecessor.
- The second `if`: `if(!node->prev_ && node->next_)`:

  This means you are deleting the head, but the list will not be empty after the node is deleted. In this case, you must set the head of the list to point to the new head, which will be the node pointed to by `node->next_`. Also, you have the similar problem with `free()` as before.

Addressing those two points, your code should do something along the lines of this:

```
void removeNode(struct student_record_node *node){
    if(!node->next_ && !node->prev_){
        your_list->head = NULL; // Remove head - List is now empty.
        student_record_node_deallocate(node);
        node = NULL; // Set freed pointer to NULL, for safety.
    }
    else if(!node->prev_ && node->next_){
        your_list->head = node->next_; // Set the head to the new head.
        student_record_node_deallocate(node);
        node = NULL; // Set freed pointer to NULL, for safety.
    }
    else if(node->next_ && node->prev_){
        node->prev_->next_ = node->next_;
        node->next_->prev_ = node->prev_;
        student_record_node_deallocate(node);
        node = NULL; // Set freed pointer to NULL, for safety.
    }
    else if(node->prev_ && !node->next_){
        node->prev_->next_ = NULL;
        student_record_node_dealocate(node);
        node = NULL; // Set freed pointer to NULL, for safety.
    }
}
```